# Weird behavior with setTimer in window:unload

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an angular app. But now I am stuck with logging the user out when the tab is clsoed, but not when its refreshed or some other tab is focused.
To do that I am using the `window.unload` event. However this on its own is not enough because this would also logout the user when refreshing the page. So from another SO question I found that I should wrap the request in an `setTimeout` call like so

```
  @HostListener('window:unload')
  onUnload() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigator.sendBeacon(*logout_url*);
    }, 0)
  }
```

There is just one very weird problem with this code. The request is only fired every second time I close the tab.
Example: open my page in new tab -> close tab -> nothing happens -> open my page in new tab again -> close tab -> request is sent. And then it starts all over again: open page -> close tab -> nothing happens -> open page again -> request is sent.

I figured it must have something to do with the `setTimeout` but afaik I cant remove that because I need it so the request is not sent when refreshing the page.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: General comments: 1) Are you sure you need to log your user out when they close (*any*) tab displaying your app? 2) `onunload` is said to be unreliable (for this purpose) and is discouraged for modern browsers. 3) Have you considered having short-lived session duration and use "keep-alive"/"hearbeat" "pings" from your app instead?